# Restrict JSON array to only accept items of a specific type

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a moderately complex JSON schema containing an array which shall only accept items of two specific types. For some reason, after adding an item of a third type, validation succeeds. Can you help me find what I overlook?

I've made a small fragment of the scheme with only the affected parts:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",    
       
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    
    "properties": {

        "trainzMeshes": {
            "title": "Trainz Meshes",
            "description": "Specifications of Trainz meshes to create as FBX files and comments specified as an array.",
            "type": "array",      
            "additionalItems": false,
            "items": {
                "anyOf": [ 
                    { 
                        "comment": {
                            "$ref": "#/$defs/comment" 
                        },
                        "minItems": 0
                    }, 
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/$defs/trainzMesh",
                        "minItems": 1
                    } 
                ]
            }                          
        },
    },
        

    
    "$defs": {

        "comment": {
            "title": "Comment",
            "description": "A comment to help you remember what comes next. You may include as many comments as you wish.",
            "oneOf": [
                { 
                    "type": "string" 
                },
                { 
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "minItems": 1
                }
            ]            
        },

        "trainzMesh": {
            "title": "Trainz Mesh Composition Wrapper",
            "description": "Container for the specification of a Trainz mesh describing what FBX file and Trainz asset to create from which of your Blender objects.",
            
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["trainzMeshComposition"],
            "additionalProperties": false,

            "properties": {
                "trainzMeshComposition": {
                    "title": "Trainz Mesh Composition Settings",
                    "description": "Specification of a Trainz mesh describing what FBX file and Trainz asset to create from which of your Blender objects. You may include comments as well.",
                    
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": ["name", "blenderExportSpecifications"],
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    
                    "properties": {

                        "comment": {
                            "$ref": "#/$defs/comment"
                        },

                        "name": {
                            "title": "Trainz Mesh File Name (Pattern)",
                            "description": "Name (pattern) for the FBX files to create.",
                            "type": "string"
                        },

                        "blenderExportSpecifications": {

                            "title": "Blender Export Specifications",
                            "description": "Specifies one or more Blender objects, with optionally assigning a material and UV map to each, to include them in the Trainz mesh FBX file.",
                            
                            "type": "array",
                            "minItems": 1,
                            "additionalItems": false,
                            "items": {
                                "anyOf": [
                                    {   "$ref": "#/$defs/blenderExportSpecification",
                                        "minContains": 1
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "comment": {
                                            "$ref": "#/$defs/comment"
                                        },
                                        "minContains": 0
                                    }
                                ]                                
                            }
                        }            
                    }
                }
            }
        },            


        "blenderExportSpecification": {
            "title": "Blender Export Specification",
            "description": "Specifies one or more Blender objects, with optionally assigning a material and UV map to each, to include them in the Trainz mesh FBX file.",
            
            "type": "object",              
            "anyOf": [
                { "required": ["scopeToCollections"] },
                { "required": ["includeObjectsByName"] },
                { "required": ["includeObjectsByPattern"] },
                { "required": ["includeObjectsByConditions"] },
                { "required": ["excludeObjectsByName"] },
                { "required": ["excludeObjectsByPattern"] },
                { "required": ["excludeObjectsByConditions"] },
                { "required": ["dropModifiers"] },
                { "required": ["material"] },
                { "required": ["uvMap"] }
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false,

            "properties": {

                "scopeToCollections":  {
                    "title": "Scope to Collections",
                    "description": "A regular expression specifying collection name patterns or a list specifying collection names. Only Blender objects contained under referenced collections in your Blender file will be processed for inclusion for exporting.",
                    
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "minItems": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },

                "includeObjectsByName": {
                    "title": "Include Object(s) By Name",
                    "description": "The name or (in the form of a string array) names of the Blender object(s) to export and to which parameters in this export specification apply.",

                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "minItems": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },

                "includeObjectsByPattern":  {         
                    "title": "Include Objects By Name Pattern",
                    "description": "A regular expression specifying an object name pattern. Only objects within the scope selected by scopeToCollections and matching this pattern will be exported.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "regex"
                },

                "includeObjectsByConditions":  {         
                    "title": "Include Objects By Condition",
                    "description": "A pair of a property name and a value pattern. Only Blender objects having this property with a value matching the specified value pattern will be included in the export.",
                    
                    "type": "array",
                    "minItems": 1,

                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/$defs/objectPropertyCondition"
                    }                    
                },

                "excludeObjectsByName": {
                    "title": "Exclude Object(s) By Name",
                    "description": "Name(s) of object(s) to omit when exporting within this export specification.",

                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "type": "string" 
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "minItems": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },

                "excludeObjectsByPattern":  {         
                    "title": "Exclude Objects By Name Pattern",
                    "description": "A regular expression specifying an object name pattern. Matching objects will be omitted when exporting within this export specification.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "regex"
                },

                "excludeObjectsByConditions":  {         
                    "title": "Exclude Objects By Condition",
                    "description": "A pair of a property name and a value pattern. Blender objects having this property with a value matching the specified value pattern will not be included in the export.",
                    
                    "type": "array",
                    "minItems": 1,

                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/$defs/objectPropertyCondition"
                    }                    
                },

                "dropModifiers": {
                    "title": "Modifiers to Drop",
                    "description": "Name(s) of modifiers to hide before exporting the objects.",

                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "title": "Name Pattern for Modifiers to Drop",
                            "description": "A regex. Modifiers with a name matching this regex will not be applied.",
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "regex"                           
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Names of Modifiers to Drop",
                            "description": "A list of names of modifiers to hide before exporting.",
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "minItems": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                
                "material": {
                    "title": "Material to Apply",
                    "description": "Name of the material in your Blender file to apply to the object before exporting. The name shall conform to Trainz specifications.",
                    "type": "string"
                },

                "uvMap": {
                    "title": "UV Map to Apply",
                    "description": "Name of the UV map created for the Blender object to switch to before exporting.",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }          
        },

        "objectPropertyCondition": {

            "title": "Object Property Condition",
            "description": "Description of a condition composed of a custom property defined for Blender objects and a pattern for matching values",
            
            "required": ["name", "valuePattern"],
            "additionalProperties": false,
            
            "properties": {

                "name": {
                    "title": "Condition Property Name",
                    "description": "Name of the property containing the condition.",
                    "type": "string"
                },

                "valuePattern": {   
                    "title": "Condition Value Pattern",
                    "description": "A pattern which the value of the property shall match to meet the condition.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "regex"
                }
            }            
                 
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this JSON based on that scheme:

```json
{   
    "trainzMeshes": [
        { "comment": "*****************************************************************" },
        { "comment": "  STATION NAME DISPLAY - SIZE S                                  " },
        { "comment": "*****************************************************************" },
        { "comment": "---------------------------- Lod 0 ------------------------------" },
        {
            "trainzMeshComposition": {
                "name": "name-display-S-daytime-lod0n",
                "blenderExportSpecifications": [
                    {
                        "includeObject": [
                            "Name Display Console - S [lod0]",
                            "Name Display - S - Default [lod0]"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The validator I have for VS Code, as well as Newtonsoft's validator at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ finds that the JSON conforms to the schema, whereas I would expect "includeObject" to violate it for two reasons.

1. If the "includeObject" key is considered a part of the subschema "blenderExportSpecification", which has a couple of properties, but none of them is "includeObject", moreover additionalProperties is set to false. So if it's considered as part of "blenderExportSpecification", violation shall occur.
2. In case the validator finds the object with "includeObject" is not an object of the "blenderExportSpecification" type, I would expect the failure at the array level, as it's not one of the two allowed types.

I tried playing with a lot of things, such as changing "oneOf" to "anyOf", to change the oneOf > items structure to items > oneOf, but no way could I make it fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `anyOf` schemas are unconstrained because you defined `comment` as a property, but you didn't use the `properties` keyword, which JSON Schema interprets as the property `comment` is unconstrained. Hopefully that makes sense.

You also have some invalid usage of `minItems`, and `minContains` which goes unused because you are not using `contains` keyword. Also, the location of these keywords used would be incorrect as a sibling to the `$ref`.

try this...

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "trainzMeshes": {
            "title": "Trainz Meshes",
            "description": "Specifications of Trainz meshes to create as FBX files and comments specified as an array.",
            "type": "array",
            "additionalItems": false,
            "items": {
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "comment": {
                                "$ref": "#/$defs/comment"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/$defs/trainzMesh"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "$defs": {
        "comment": {
            "title": "Comment",
            "description": "A comment to help you remember what comes next. You may include as many comments as you wish.",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "minItems": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        "trainzMesh": {
            "title": "Trainz Mesh Composition Wrapper",
            "description": "Container for the specification of a Trainz mesh describing what FBX file and Trainz asset to create from which of your Blender objects.",
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "trainzMeshComposition"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "trainzMeshComposition": {
                    "title": "Trainz Mesh Composition Settings",
                    "description": "Specification of a Trainz mesh describing what FBX file and Trainz asset to create from which of your Blender objects. You may include comments as well.",
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": [
                        "name",
                        "blenderExportSpecifications"
                    ],
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "comment": {
                            "$ref": "#/$defs/comment"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "title": "Trainz Mesh File Name (Pattern)",
                            "description": "Name (pattern) for the FBX files to create.",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "blenderExportSpecifications": {
                            "title": "Blender Export Specifications",
                            "description": "Specifies one or more Blender objects, with optionally assigning a material and UV map to each, to include them in the Trainz mesh FBX file.",
                            "type": "array",
                            "minItems": 1,
                            "additionalItems": false,
                            "items": {
                                "anyOf": [
                                    {
                                        "$ref": "#/$defs/blenderExportSpecification"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "additionalProperties": false,
                                        "properties": {
                                            "comment": {
                                                "$ref": "#/$defs/comment"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "blenderExportSpecification": {
            "title": "Blender Export Specification",
            "description": "Specifies one or more Blender objects, with optionally assigning a material and UV map to each, to include them in the Trainz mesh FBX file.",
            "type": "object",
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "required": [
                        "scopeToCollections"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "includeObjectsByName"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "includeObjectsByPattern"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "includeObjectsByConditions"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "excludeObjectsByName"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "excludeObjectsByPattern"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "excludeObjectsByConditions"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "dropModifiers"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "material"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "uvMap"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "scopeToCollections": {
                    "title": "Scope to Collections",
                    "description": "A regular expression specifying collection name patterns or a list specifying collection names. Only Blender objects contained under referenced collections in your Blender file will be processed for inclusion for exporting.",
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "minItems": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "includeObjectsByName": {
                    "title": "Include Object(s) By Name",
                    "description": "The name or (in the form of a string array) names of the Blender object(s) to export and to which parameters in this export specification apply.",
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "minItems": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "includeObjectsByPattern": {
                    "title": "Include Objects By Name Pattern",
                    "description": "A regular expression specifying an object name pattern. Only objects within the scope selected by scopeToCollections and matching this pattern will be exported.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "regex"
                },
                "includeObjectsByConditions": {
                    "title": "Include Objects By Condition",
                    "description": "A pair of a property name and a value pattern. Only Blender objects having this property with a value matching the specified value pattern will be included in the export.",
                    "type": "array",
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/$defs/objectPropertyCondition"
                    }
                },
                "excludeObjectsByName": {
                    "title": "Exclude Object(s) By Name",
                    "description": "Name(s) of object(s) to omit when exporting within this export specification.",
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "minItems": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "excludeObjectsByPattern": {
                    "title": "Exclude Objects By Name Pattern",
                    "description": "A regular expression specifying an object name pattern. Matching objects will be omitted when exporting within this export specification.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "regex"
                },
                "excludeObjectsByConditions": {
                    "title": "Exclude Objects By Condition",
                    "description": "A pair of a property name and a value pattern. Blender objects having this property with a value matching the specified value pattern will not be included in the export.",
                    "type": "array",
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/$defs/objectPropertyCondition"
                    }
                },
                "dropModifiers": {
                    "title": "Modifiers to Drop",
                    "description": "Name(s) of modifiers to hide before exporting the objects.",
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "title": "Name Pattern for Modifiers to Drop",
                            "description": "A regex. Modifiers with a name matching this regex will not be applied.",
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "regex"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Names of Modifiers to Drop",
                            "description": "A list of names of modifiers to hide before exporting.",
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "minItems": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "material": {
                    "title": "Material to Apply",
                    "description": "Name of the material in your Blender file to apply to the object before exporting. The name shall conform to Trainz specifications.",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "uvMap": {
                    "title": "UV Map to Apply",
                    "description": "Name of the UV map created for the Blender object to switch to before exporting.",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "objectPropertyCondition": {
            "title": "Object Property Condition",
            "description": "Description of a condition composed of a custom property defined for Blender objects and a pattern for matching values",
            "required": [
                "name",
                "valuePattern"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "title": "Condition Property Name",
                    "description": "Name of the property containing the condition.",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "valuePattern": {
                    "title": "Condition Value Pattern",
                    "description": "A pattern which the value of the property shall match to meet the condition.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "regex"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The diff

[image: first anyOf]

[image: second anyOf]

---

EDIT, based on your comment for additional requirements:

- I only want to allow one `trainzMesh` object and any number of `comment` objects

This is one way to do it.

- always require the first index to be a `trainzMesh` object. We do that with `items` as an array `[]`. This creates positional arguments.
- I added the constraint `minItems: 1` to always require at least the `trainzMesh` object. `comment`s are optional.
- any additional array item must be a `comment` object and no `additionalProperties` are allowed in that object schema.

```json
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "trainzMeshes": {
      "title": "Trainz Meshes",
      "description": "Specifications of Trainz meshes to create as FBX files and comments specified as an array.",
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/trainzMesh"
        }
      ],
      "additionalItems": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "comment": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/comment"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: just a side note.. `$defs` was introduced in JSON Schema 2019-09, draft-07 would use `definitions`.  But, because it's a valid JSON reference, it resolves correctly, although some tooling may not be able to interpret it, as expected.

Comment: you should be able to change the `anyOf` to `oneOf` without any additional legwork.

Comment: Thanks, more than a great start! I actually did not see why only `comment` had to be "wrapped", but when I wrapped `trainzMesh`, for example, the same way, it worked fine.

Now how can I apply the limits per data type in an array if, say, I only want to allow one `trainzMesh` object and any number of 'comment' objects? Researched and played a lot with no further success.

Comment: can you give a sample payload?

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy! I guess I cannot do much if I want to allow users to include at least one comment first, then the trainzMesh, then any number of comments. Probably this is beyond what a schema can define.

Comment: Just out of very real curiosity, can you explain why trainzMesh doesn't need to be wrapped in an object like comment needs to be wrapped? I cannot find any difference between the structure of the two, but I may easily overlook something.

Comment: I think you are referring to the `anyOf`, and the reason we don't need to use a `properties` keyword is there exists a reference to another schema in the form of a JSON pointer which is resolved and applied to the original location of the `$ref`. https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring#dollarref

Comment: regarding the definition, I may be wrong, but my understanding is there is no way to define an open beginning of an array index for any number of comments and then define an explicit index for the trainzMesh without explicitly defining the number of possible comments.  You would do that with `items: [idx1, idx2, idx3, idx4, idx5,idx6, trainzMesh]`